# Create all possible combinations of n elements with m levels

Tags: r

I am looking for a short R script to create all possible combinations of 10 elements, each element has the same three levels.

```
a <- letters[1:10]  # elements
b <- 1:3            # levels
```

the expected result is something like

```
    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j
    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2
    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   3
    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   1
    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   2
    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   3
    ......                                  
    3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3
```

where the first row is the title, other rows are the combinations. Thank you for helps.

Comment: This is what I want. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was surprising that you do need so many (`3 ^ 10`) combinations.

```
expand.grid(replicate(10, 1:3, simplify = FALSE))
```